# Embed SymmetricDs for CDC (Change Data Capture )

Tags: java, symmetricds, change-data-capture

Is it possible to embed Symmetric Ds for CDC operations ? If yes how can I do that ? If no is there other open source tools that can be embedded for CDC ? Other than kafka and Debezium ?

Comment: Yes this is possible. The SymmetricDs user guide gives instruction on how to embed. http://www.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/doc/3.8/html/user-guide.html#_embedded